# Cordova Google analytics plugin works on iOS, but breaks Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-analytics

I am using Cordova 5.1.1 and the `com.analytics.google 1.2.2 "Google Analytics Plugin"`. Anyone else experienced this issue?

The problem is as simple as:

*On iOS:*

With it **INSTALLED**, the build **works**.

**WITHOUT** it, the build **fails** and outputs the following message:

```
    ** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/Easyodds.app/Easyodds normal i386
(1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,Easyodds.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,Easyodds,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

*On Android:*

**WITHOUT** it, the build is **successful**.

With it **INSTALLED** the build **fails** and outputs the following message:

```
/Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/android/src/com/appfeel/cordova/analytics/CPGoogleAnalytics.java:693: error: cannot find symbol
      productAction = createProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_CHECKOUT_OPTION, options);
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable ACTION_CHECKOUT_OPTION
  location: class ProductAction
1 error
:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 18.554 secs

/Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/stuartjones/Documents/eo-app/easyodds/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```